# CSS divs in one row with overflow-x scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow

I want to have a list with fixed height and inside items in one row. If the amount of items exceed the width, I want an overflow-x scroll so the items shouldn't be pushed to next row.

So far i've played around with inline-block for ul/li and float left for divs but they all get pushed to the next row..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you should post the code of your best try so far;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width: 500px;
}
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin-right:20px;
  white-space:normal;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/3dsign/gw35yq9p/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using display:inline-block and floatings ,try learning Flexbox which its much easier and has incredible features :[Flexbox Tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

So if you want, use this:

```
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align:top;
  white-space:normal;
}
```